# Collect is not collecting properly with non-commutative algebra

Tags: ncalgebra

I'm using the `NCAlgebra` package to do some error analysis of operator split methods. I am trying to reproduce the simple examples in Mathematica, but I'm coming across some strange behavior and I think it may all be related to me doing something wrong.

If I look at finding the error for Lie operator splitting and Strang operator splitting, the results come out strange:

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`

SetCommutative[dt, u0];
SetNonCommutative[Dx];
SetNonCommutative[B];


ue = (1 + dt*(Dx + B) + dt^2/2*(Dx + B)^2 + dt^3/6*(Dx + B)^3)*u0;

uL = ((1 + dt*Dx + dt^2/2*Dx^2 + dt^3/6*Dx^3) ** (1 + dt*B + 
       dt^2/2*B^2 + dt^3/6*B^3))*u0;

uS = ((1 + (dt/2)*Dx + (dt/2)^2/2*Dx^2 + (dt/2)^3/6*
        Dx^3 + (dt/2)^4/Factorial[4]*Dx^4 + (dt/2)^5/Factorial[5]*
        Dx^5) ** (1 + dt*B + dt^2/2*B^2 + 
       dt^3/6*B^3) ** (1 + (dt/2)*Dx + (dt/2)^2/2*Dx^2 + (dt/2)^3/6*
        Dx^3 + (dt/2)^4/Factorial[4]*Dx^4 + (dt/2)^5/Factorial[5]*
        Dx^5))*u0;

Substitute[
 NCCollect[NCExpand[(uL - ue)/u0], {dt, dt^2, dt^3}], {dt^3 -> 0, 
  dt^4 -> 0, dt^5 -> 0, dt^6 -> 0, dt^7 -> 0, dt^8 -> 0, dt^9 -> 0, 
  dt^10 -> 0, dt^11 -> 0, dt^12 -> 0}]
Substitute[
 NCCollect[NCExpand[(uS - ue)/u0], {dt, dt^2, dt^3}], {dt^4 -> 0, 
  dt^5 -> 0, dt^6 -> 0, dt^7 -> 0, dt^8 -> 0, dt^9 -> 0, dt^10 -> 0, 
  dt^11 -> 0, dt^12 -> 0, dt^13 -> 0}]
```

Okay, so it seems simple enough (although really ugly -- I know, Mathematica is not more forte). The results I get are:

```
-B dt^2 Dx + dt^2 Dx ** B

dt^2 (-B Dx - Dx^2/4) + dt^3 (-((B^2 Dx)/2) - Dx^3/8 - B ** Dx^2/2) + 
 dt^2 (B ** Dx/2 + Dx ** B/2 + Dx ** Dx/4) + 
 dt^3 (B ** Dx^2/8 + B^2 ** Dx/4 + Dx ** B^2/4 + Dx ** Dx^2/16 + 
    Dx^2 ** B/8 + Dx^2 ** Dx/16 + Dx ** B ** Dx/4)
```

So now my issues/concerns/questions:

1. Why is it not collecting terms correctly? For example, it didn't collect in `dt^2` in the first result and didn't collect everything in either `dt^2` or `dt^3` in the second.
2. Why would it think that `B Dx` is different from `B ** Dx`? Likewise, it thinks `Dx^2` is not the same as `Dx ** Dx`. And how does it even make sense that a variable would not commute with itself?

Something tells me I input something weird/wrong and that's why it's doing this.

Any insight would be helpful. This is the first step and I'd hate to have to return to pen-and-paper doing these multiplications.

Comment: Also, please feel free to add the correct tags. I have no clue what tags would be appropriate...

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely sure about what you want to do but you should call NCCollect (or standard Collect) on `dt` alone. For example:

```
NCCollect[NCExpand[(uL - ue)/u0], {dt}]
```

Because in your case `dt` is commutative the standard Mathematica `Collect` will also work. For the same reason you do not need `Substitute`, but `ReplaceAll`. Note that in recent versions of [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) `Substitute` has been replaced by the more powerful and consistent `NCReplaceAll`.

Looks like you're doing some kind of directional derivative. If so, check out the command `NCDirectionalD`.